# How to trace app crash in heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, restify

My REST api heroku app (using restify) crashes and I dont know why. In heroku logs there is only line:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/some/api/path host=some.host.com fwd="83.28.44.34" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I tried adding this:

```
process.on('uncaughtException',function(err){
    console.log('#########');
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
});
```

But it does not writes anything to logs.

The problem is I don't know if app crashes during http request because there are some functions that may be fired even after request is complete...

How I can trace what crashes my app?

Comment: Try with `heroku logs --tail` while calling the endpoint that triggers the error, what do you get?

Comment: Yes I am watching the logs but the problem is I see only "App crashed". I want stack trace...

Comment: `console.log(err.trace)` should give you the trace, but since you are not seeing anything I doubt this will work.

Comment: No - I dont know how and where catch error...